# Cordova FCM - Build Error: Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.google.gms.google-services']

Tags: android, ios, cordova, firebase, firebase-notifications

I have a Cordova app with Android and iOS, and I am trying to add [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) so I can send push notification. I have followed the setup instructions on the site multiple times and continue to get the same build error.

Here is the error I get when I run Cordova build

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Me\workspace\App\platforms\android\build.gradle' line: 326

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.google.gms.google-services']
   > For input string: "+"
```

This is what is on the last line of the build.gradle file `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`, which is what the setup instruction says to do.

I have made an account, got my package name from `AndroidManifest.xml`, then added the `google-services.json` to the main in the Android project, and then added the 3 lines in the `build.gradle` file, but I continue to get this error.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help.

Comment: By *added the google-services.json to the main in the Android project*, do you mean you added the json file in the main folder? If so, shouldn't it be in the **app** folder?

Comment: @AL. I put in the the MyProjetName/platfroms/android folder it is at the same level as the build.gradle file

Comment: I don't think that's the right folder. It has to be in the **app** folder. You can go to it by the Project browser in Android studio

Answer (score 7):

I had similar issues.

My fix was to edit ./platforms/android/project.properties

I changed the + to 10.0.1 on all the google services. (make sure the SDK is up-to-date)

ie:

```
cordova.system.library.1=com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+
```

to

```
cordova.system.library.1=com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.1
```

Do a build and all worked.

Comment: I can confirm that this answer is working. Thanks for that.

Comment: I dont have project.properties inside platforms/android.